# How to limit table search to specific rows that contain specific text in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am searching in my table with a function:

```
//search field for table
$("#search_field").keyup(function() {
var value = this.value;

$("#menu_table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    var id = $(this).find("td").text();
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);

});});
```

Fourth coulmn of data is **Type** i.e. Chicken, Kebabs etc.
I want to search only in those rows whose 4th column contains ('Chicken'). It should not search in rows whose **Type** is 'Kebabs'. The code above is searching in all rows.

Comment: You can use `index()` OR if you can/have assigned classes to your rows, you can have use that class as `find("tr.CLASSNAMNe")`

Comment: I am getting data from database. Will it work on it? Can I use **contains** instead assigning classes to rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) the rows and apply your code only to the filtered row like in:

```
$('#menu_table tr:gt(0)').filter(function(idx, ele) {
            return $(ele).find('td:eq(3)').text() == 'Chicken';
}).each(function(index, ele) {
    var id = $(this).find("td").text();
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
});
```

Another way to filter is based on [:nth-child() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('#menu_table tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return ele.textContent == 'Chicken';
}).closest('tr').each(function(index, ele) {
    var id = $(this).find("td").text();
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
});
```

```js
$('#menu_table tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return ele.textContent == 'Chicken';
}).closest('tr').each(function(index, ele) {
    var id = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    var typ = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    console.log('ID:' + id + ' Type: ' + typ);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="menu_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="item_id">ID</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="price">Price</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="type">Type</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="image">Image</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="description">Description</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="cooking">Instructions</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="ingredients">Ingredients</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="warnings">Warnings</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="Storage">Storage</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="Size">Size</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="edit">Edit</th>
        <th class="centerText" data-field="delete">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="text-align:center;" id="menu_table_data">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>instruction</td>
        <td>ingredients</td>
        <td>warnings</td>
        <td>storage</td>
        <td>size</td>
        <td>edit</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>instruction</td>
        <td>ingredients</td>
        <td>warnings</td>
        <td>storage</td>
        <td>size</td>
        <td>edit</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>not Chicken</td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>instruction</td>
        <td>ingredients</td>
        <td>warnings</td>
        <td>storage</td>
        <td>size</td>
        <td>edit</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>Chicken</td>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>instruction</td>
        <td>ingredients</td>
        <td>warnings</td>
        <td>storage</td>
        <td>size</td>
        <td>edit</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`:contains(text)`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
$("#menu_table").find("tr:contains('Chicken')").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).children('td').eq(3).text() == "Chicken"){
        /* Do something */
    }
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kvvnjmup/4/

```js
$('#menu_table').find('tr:contains("Chicken")').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('td').eq(3).text() == "Chicken"){
        alert($(this).prop('id'));
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="menu_table">
<tbody><tr id="1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Chicken</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Chicken</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>pasta</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
 <tr id="4">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Chicken</td>
  <td>pasta</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess this is what @Shaifu is asking. If the 5th row contains "Chicken" then it shouldn't search for it.

Comment: Sorry, I coded according to the title. The code has been adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Let me see your suggestion.

Comment: @Shaifu This code will only return rows which 4th column contains Chicken, not Kebabs. I don't need to edit this answer for it to work even after your update. Also: please be aware that StackOverflow is not a freelancing website. You should be able to adapt this code to your needs. We are not your personal coding army.